# Add another column to existing list

Tags: python, sql, data-structures

I'm starting to learn python and I'm trying to do an exercise where I have to save in a "rows" variable some stock data coming from a SQL query, like this:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM user_quote WHERE user_id=:userid", userid=session["user_id"])
```

This will return 4 columns `(id, user_id, symbol, name)`

Then, for every row the query returns I'll get the last known price of that stock from an API, and I want to add that information to another column in my `rows` variable. Is there a way to do this? Should I use another approach?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `db.execute()` doesn't return rows. You need to call `db.fetchone()` or `db.fetchall()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what type the rows variable is, but you can just add an additional column in the SELECT:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT *, 0 NewCol FROM user_quote WHERE user_id=:userid", userid=session["user_id"])
```

Assuming `rows` is mutable, this will provide a placeholder for the new value.

Comment: The additional column comes from an API that he calls after fetching from the DB.

Comment: why do you need a placeholder? Just use `rows.append(price)`

Comment: Correct. I clarified my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `rows` tuple to a list, then you can use `append()` to add the price.

```
rows = list(rows)
rows.append(price)
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the reply.
How would I be able to choose the "column name" using this?
I'm using this variable to build a table in a HTML file, like:
{% for row in rows %}
                    <td>{{ row["symbol"] }}</td>
{% endfor %}

So, I would need to know the column name to access it in the loop

Comment: It's not a dictionary, so you can't use named indexes. So `row["symbol"]` should be `row[2]`, etc.